# What is the best way to filter/search through large data sets in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

Say I am filtering a list of 25,000 songs based on a searchTerm:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({ (...)
  matchingSongs: Ember.computed('searchTerm', function() {
    return this.get('model.songs').filter(function(song) {
       return song.get('title').indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1;
    });
  })
})
```

This feels a little laggy. Is this the right way to go about it in Ember 2.0? Or should I delegate the searching to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider if such big dataset is really needed for your user to store it locally. First, you make them download a huge payload from your API (think about mobile / low speed connections), second you expose huge dataset of your database to external world.

It may turn out that delegating it to server won't make it significantly quicker when considering 25k songs. But 25k is already a lot. And depending on the local machine the speed of filtering can vary a lot.

I would definitely delegate it to server. However, if you can't, your solution is good.